# How to find out if four points are on the same plane, only by using distances?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

There is a method called [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) in order to find if 3 points are collinear, 4 points are coplanar etc. provided that all the pairwise distances are given.

However, in 2-D, there is a much simple way to determine if 3 points, $\{A,B,C\}$ are collinear: Triangle inequality!

$\neg(|AB| + |AC| = |BC|) \wedge \neg(|AB| + |BC| = |AC|) \wedge \neg(|AC| + |BC| = |AB|)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $A, B, C$ are not collinear

Is there a similar approach in 3-D?

Comment: Your link says that the determinant is a version of Heron's formula $$\triangle^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$

Now that is a little more complex than the triangle inequality perhaps, but note $s-a=0$ iff $a=b+c$. So you have a test for planarity $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)=0$ which is one formula combining your three.

Comment: @Mark Bennet That analysis makes the situation so clear. So the determinant implies this method :)

Comment: Your subject asks about coplanar points, the question about colinear points. Which one is it?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Think of the areas of the four  Triangles. It could be generallized to higher dimensions in a obvious way.

Comment: So I have to check if sum of three areas are equal to fourth one or not?

Comment: If the sum of any 3 of the four areas equals the area of the remaining one.

Comment: Well, this is not entirely true. If coplanar, four points form a rectangle. Even though there are 4 triangles $ABC$, $ABD$, $ACD$, $BCD$, the sum of three does not give the fourth.

Comment: For that you have to find out which sides make up the outer and component triangles. ..